# AWS IoT MQTT Client for Python - How do you subscribe forever?

Tags: infinite-loop, mqtt, publish-subscribe, aws-iot

I'm using the example from the samples/basicPubSub/basicPubSub.py with `useWebsocket=True`

I have some file `my_test_file.py` where I connect() and subscribe() with a message callback. Let's say the callback just writes to some log file. How can I have this file always be running, so that if I publish from somewhere else, today, tomorrow, a year from now - this log file is constantly being written to with the message?

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient

client = AWSIoTMQTTClient('client_id', useWebsocket=True)
client.configureEndpoint('host', port)
client.configureCredentials('path to cert')

client.configureAutoReconnectBackoffTime(1, 32, 20)
client.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)
client.configureDrainingFrequency(2)
client.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10)
client.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)
client.connect()

client.subscribe('topic name', 1, _some_callback_func)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Is having an infinite while loop at the end of `my_test_file.py` the only way? With the infinite while loop, I run the file and it's a blocking process, but it is infinitely subscribed. Is it a combination of a systemd service and this infinite while loop? I saw some `loop_forever()` methods in the Paho MQTT client, does the aws iot mqtt client have something similar? Is loop_forever() just implementing an infinite while loop?

Comment: Post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite looping is the right way to handle with that, as long as you know what to do, not interrupting the main process (core logic). To do so, I recommend you isolate this script in a new python file to be runned by the main python script as a subprocess. So, before you start with hands on, read [Multiprocessing - process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Usually something always need to keeping the Python process running on memory, unless something reboot the OS unexpectedly.

It seems not be an elegant way to handle with it, but I advise you to construct an execution management structure behind this Python script, like always initiate your python script after "boot loader" machine/device, make an another watchdog script, or something else like that, to prevent some internet connections problems, forcing the system to be rebooted or reconnect to the internet.